# NServicebus receive messages without all the NServicebus specific stuff

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nservicebus

I am new to NServicebus and have struggled to find an answer in the documentation.

I am trying to receive a message that is posted to Amazon SQS in a simple JSON format like this:

```
"MyMessage": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Field1": "text",
    "Field2": 1,
    "Field3": false
}
```

However whenever this gets sent to the queue my NServicebus subscriber says it is a poison message and doesn't try to handle it.

I realize that this message is missing a lot of NServicebus stuff because when I publish a message via NServicebus it looks like this:

```
{
    "Headers": {
        "NServiceBus.MessageId": "a244a014-e331-41e6-b6ca-aed6011af905",
        "NServiceBus.MessageIntent": "Publish",
        "NServiceBus.ConversationId": "e42f0308-4c51-4787-ade0-aed6011af90f",
        "NServiceBus.CorrelationId": "a244a014-e331-41e6-b6ca-aed6011af905",
        "NServiceBus.OriginatingMachine": "DESKTOP-1234567",
        "NServiceBus.OriginatingEndpoint": "endpoint",
        "$.diagnostics.originating.hostid": "da7dce712dfbc0f093aa30eb7f25d2b4",
        "NServiceBus.ContentType": "application/json",
        "NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes": "Type",
        "NServiceBus.Version": "7.7.3",
        "NServiceBus.TimeSent": "2022-07-18 17:10:16:400164 Z"
    },
    "Body": "Base 64 encoded string here",
    "S3BodyKey": null
}
```

The problem is the message I am receiving is not published via NServicebus and comes in the format I showed above. It doesn't have all of the headers and a body that is base64 encoded.

Is there a way to set up NServicebus to be able to receive and handle such a message? Or is it just not built to handle stuff like this?

Note: This is a .Net 6 application

Edit: I found this article that mentions how NServicebus can receive messages without all the headers, but it doesn't mention how.

https://www.bradjolicoeur.com/Article/nsb-features-message-headers

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called Native Send and is actually [documented](https://docs.particular.net/transports/sqs/operations-scripting#native-send). You have to conform your messages to the format NServiceBus expects in order to be able to have handlers correctly process it.

A native send function would look like this:

```cs
public static async Task SendMessage(IAmazonSQS sqsClient, string queue, string messageBody, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    var bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody);
    var base64Body = Convert.ToBase64String(bodyBytes);
    var serializedMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        Headers = headers,
        Body = base64Body,
    });
    var queueUrlResponse = await sqsClient.GetQueueUrlAsync(QueueNameHelper.GetSqsQueueName(queue));
    await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(queueUrlResponse.QueueUrl, serializedMessage);
}
```

To use this you'd need to specify message type and some other header values:

```
await SendMessage(
    sqsClient: client,
    queue: "samples-sqs-nativeintegration",
    messageBody: "{Property:'PropertyValue'}",
    headers: new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes", "MessageTypeToSend"},
        {"NServiceBus.MessageId", "99C7320B-A645-4C74-95E8-857EAB98F4F9"}
    }
);
```